# Seeing Intrinsic Curvature of a Surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Is there any issue with characterizing a surface as being *intrinsically flat* by saying "at no point does it either resemble a pringle (saddle) or a bullet (elliptic paraboloid)?" I'm trying to develop an eye for seeing the intrinsic curvature in a 2-dimensional surface.

Based on Gauss' initial definition of the intrinsic curvature of a surface at a point $p$ as the product of principal curvatures, $\kappa(p)=\kappa_{min}\kappa_{max}$, I think my characterization is reasonable if informal.

It also seems intuitively telling to take something intrinsically flat like a piece of paper or a placemat and give it some kind of intrinsic curvature only to have it resist by forming kinks and cusps.

Comment: do you know the covariant derivative on $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: @janmarqz It measures the part of the change in a vector field along a curve that's not due to the 'twisting' of the tangent plane?

Comment: the definition of the curvature as the product of the principal curvatures is _not_ intrinsic. See, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794327/which-of-principal-curvature-gaussian-curvature-and-mean-curvature-is-intrinsic

Comment: @Thomas Maybe I should have said _Gaussian curvature_ instead of _intrinsic curvature_ to make clear that I wasn't claiming this to be an intrinsic definition, merely an _intrinsic quantity_. I just want to be able to look at a surface and say "that is intrinsically flat" or "that has intrinsic curvature" and I'm curious how other people apply their understanding of Gaussian curvature when looking at everyday objects.

Comment: $\kappa_{min}$ and $\kappa_{max}$ are the eigenvalues of the Weingarten's matrix of the surface.

Comment: It depends on the purpose of characterizing. If it's for your own intuition, then qualitatively _mostly yes_. It's necessary to say _mostly_ because, for example, a surface with one large principal curvature, like a thin tube, has wildly differing Gaussian curvature depending on the other (possibly visually indistinguishable from zero) principal curvature.

Comment: @user3257842 What you've stated is wrong. You have accounted for cylinders, but there are also cones and tangent developable surfaces.

Comment: You keep using the word intrinsic, but everything you talk about is extrinsic (i.e., depends on the embedding in $\Bbb R^3$). I would recommend you break this habit :) But if you don't have an elliptic point or a hyperbolic (saddle) point, then you have either a parabolic point or a planar point.

Comment: @TedShifrin I guess I need to get clear about the meaning of intrinsic vs. extrinsic, I thought that the "Egregious theorem" implied that even though the principle curvatures are extrinsic their product is describing something intrinsic (Gaussian curvature). Sort of like how a covariant and contravariant quantity can come together to describe an invariant quantity such as the trace.
I'm tickled that you responded to my post, thank you!

Comment: Sure, Gaussian curvature *is* intrinsic. But talking about saddle points and elliptic points is purely extrinsic!

Comment: Thank you jan, Andrew, and Ted for your replies.

Comment: My takeaways have been:
1) Be more judicious about what I call intrinsic, while Gaussian curvature is intrinsic, all the ways I was thinking about it (principal curvatures, pringles etc.) were extrinsic features of the surface.
2) The principle curvatures are the eigenvalues of the Weingarten matrix a.k.a. the matrix of the shape operator.*
3) Andrew made an interesting point about the limits of the "eyeballing" method of estimating Gaussian curvature due to the scale of one of the principal curvatures.

Comment: I think I finally understand the remark in Ted's book about how Gauss viewed $\kappa$ as the distortion of signed areas under the Gauss map. I didn't quite piece together how the principal directions being eigenvectors of the shape operator meant that a small curvilinear rectangle with sides given by the principal directions would be mapped to a dilated rectangle on the unit sphere.

Answer (score 1):

Making this community wiki in the hopes of inviting others to collect and expand on the comments.

**Extrinsic and intrinsic geometry** Loosely, the "shape" of a smooth surface in Euclidean three-space is visually perceived by its principal curvatures. While these are individually extrinsic (not determined by the first fundamental form/induced metric of the surface), their product, the Gaussian curvature, turns out to be intrinsic (determined by the induced metric).

The shape operator, whose eigenvalues are the principal curvatures, is minus the differential of the Gauss map from the surface to the unit sphere. The determinant is the Jacobian of the Gauss map. In other words, the Gaussian curvature is the "local stretching factor" for how the Gauss map distorts area.

**The limits of visualization** Whether or not Gaussian curvature can be recognized visually depends on the circumstances. For example, a surface with one large principal curvature, like a thin tube, has wildly differing Gaussian curvature depending on the other (possibly visually indistinguishable from zero) principal curvature.

- Specifically, take a point $p$ on a circle of radius greater than $1/r$ (possibly a line), draw a line $\ell$ in the plane of this circle, at distance $1/r^{2}$ from $p$ parallel to the tangent at $p$, and fix an arc $C$ lying to one side of $\ell$. If we revolve $C$ about $\ell$, we obtain a thin tube surface whose Gaussian curvature is between $-1/r$ and $1/r$ (a large interval for small positive $r$), but any two such surfaces are uniformly close (depending on the length of $C$), so visually difficult to distinguish.

Visual recognition requires care even for "surfaces with moderate principal curvatures." For example:

- The "top" and "bottom" parallels of a circular torus are parabolic (one principal curvature is $0$).
- The origin of a monkey saddle $z = x^{3} - 3xy^{2}$ is planar (both principal curvatures are $0$).

Answer (score 0):

I try to describe a 2-D situation verbally, you can look up for descriptive  symbolic equations in a university library.

If you have a brittle egg/bullet  shaped dome $K>0$ and step on it making it flat there will occur radial cracks and gaps upto its disc edge.

On the other hand if you step on a flexible ( thin rubbery) pringle saddle shape $K<0$ and step on it, it becomes flat only after overlapping radial frills and wrinkles develop on the warped flattened disc.

The intrinsic curvature or Gauss curvature $K$ is visibly seen destroyed by forced flattening induced by forces normal to the shell surface.

Non-linear strains are described by pdes of von Kármán in his work on Buckling of doubly curved structures. The theory makes no distinction between radial tension or circumferential compression in creating a dome out of a flat disc. Vice-versa  it makes no distinction between radial compression and circumferential tension in creating a saddle out of a flat disc.

This also due to the fact that it is impossible to isometrically bring pringles and egg shells to a plane without tearing or overlapping by virtue of Gauss Egregium theorem in Surface Theory. Such a mapping is not possible. The curved grid lines will break or the net will fold up.

The theorem states that in pure Bending Gauss curvature $K$ is conserved ( btw as also other items derivable by the first fundamental form of Surface theory ).

So shells or surfaces of constant Gauss curvature will crack up or warp down on being forcibly flattened depending on whether initial Gauss curvature $K$ is positive or negative.